# Connection error in apache2 under cygwin

Tags: apache, sockets, cygwin

I've been trying to use apache2 under cygwin. I have the `cygserver` service running and when I start apache it will run for perhaps 3-4 minutes and then I start getting the error:

```
Operation not permitted: connect to listener on 0.0.0.0:80
```

If I run `apachectl2 restart`, it will fix it temporarily.

If I shut down the server and run `netstat -an | grep \:80`, there's nothing listening on the port.

I've already tried running `/bin/rebaseall` from an `ash` shell to fix a previous problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your `Listen` directives to explicitly include the IP, e.g.

```
Listen 0.0.0.0:80
Listen 0.0.0.0:443
Listen 0.0.0.0:8000
```